# Saving booleans to bundles for later use in Android

Tags: android, boolean, bundle, onrestoreinstancestate, instancestate

When I try to save a `boolean` to a `Bundle`, it appears to save (from Print Outs), but then the system does not invoke the `onRestoreInstanceState` method during the process of recreation after returning from visiting the settings page of the app. (The settings are in a separate activity, tapped on from the options list in the upper right-hand corner)
According to:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html
The `onRestoreInstanceState` method will only be invoked if the `Bundle` != `null`.
I also put it into the `onCreate` method (with a null checker) and the `Bundle` always turns up null.
I don't have enough reputation to post images, but this link shows the logcat: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6vw9ynw5az5zhg/AndroidLogCat.PNG?dl=0

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String SWITCH_NAME = "com.company.name.myactivity.SWITCH";

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("RESTORING INSTANCE STATE");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            System.out.println("RECEIVED INSTANCE STATE");
        }
        System.out.println("test");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("TEST");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        System.out.println("TeSt");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("SAVING STEP 1: " + getSwitchValue());

        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(SWITCH_NAME, getSwitchValue());
        System.out.println("SAVING TEST BEFORE SUPERCLASS: " + savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SWITCH_NAME));

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("SAVING TEST AFTER SUPERCLASS: " + savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SWITCH_NAME));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private boolean getSwitchValue() {
        boolean switchValue = true;

        Switch aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        if (aSwitch != null) switchValue = aSwitch.isChecked();

        return switchValue;
    }
}
```

Thanks!
Robbie

Comment: "then the system does not invoke the onRestoreInstanceState method" -- what are you doing to try to cause `onRestoreInstanceState()` to be called? Are you rotating the screen, for example?

Comment: I attempted to answer that in an edit just now. Is there any other information that is vague or missing?

Comment: Your activity is not going to be recreated just because you visited another activity within your own app.